# Compare structs if partialeq is implemented

Tags: rust

How can I compare generic structs *if* the type parameter `T` implements `PartialEq`? I tried the following, but it doesn't compile. I understand I can just make `Foobar<T>` derive `Eq` and so on, but is it possible to have `Foobar` "inherit" or take the `PartialEq` from `T` somehow? I'm guessing something like that is already made for `Vec`, e.g. you can compare `Vec`s if and only if `T` implements `PartialEq`.

```
struct Foobar<T> {
    foobar: T
}

fn x() -> bool {
    let a = Foobar{foobar: 1};
    let b = Foobar{foobar: 2};
    a == b
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the trait by constraining the implementation when `T` is of `PartialEq` too:

```rust
impl<T> PartialEq for Foobar<T> where T: PartialEq {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.foobar == other.foobar
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2282245ca7616693cb7c61e25c8388b7)

Although the simplest solution would be to derive directly:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct Foobar<T> {
    foobar: T
}
```

It will make your inner types constrained by that trait also, it means that you would not be able to instantiate a `Foobar` struct with something that is not `PartialEq`:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct Foobar<T> {
    foobar: T
}

struct NonPartialEq {}

fn main() {
    let a = Foobar{foobar: NonPartialEq {}};
    let b = Foobar{foobar: NonPartialEq {}};
    assert!(a != b)
}
```

Something like this would not compile with:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `!=` cannot be applied to type `Foobar<NonPartialEq>`
  --> src/main.rs:11:15
   |
11 |     assert!(a != b)
   |             - ^^ - Foobar<NonPartialEq>
   |             |
   |             Foobar<NonPartialEq>
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `Foobar<NonPartialEq>`
```

So implementing it by hanb with the constrain allow you to use your struct for any type, but you will still be able to use `PartialEq` when the inner type is so.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding `Vec<_>` it's useful to scroll its documentation to see, that there is a [trait implementation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#impl-Eq) that propagates `Eq` just as you want to.

```
impl<T, A> Eq for Vec<T, A> where
    T: Eq,
    A: Allocator,
```

So you need to do the same:

```
struct Foobar<T> {
    foobar: T
}

impl<T> PartialEq for Foobar<T> where T: PartialEq {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        self.foobar == other.foobar
    }
}
impl<T> Eq for Foobar<T> where T: Eq {}

fn x() -> bool {
    let a = Foobar{foobar: 1};
    let b = Foobar{foobar: 2};
    a == b
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", x()); // false
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation! I find the documentation a bit hard to parse, I probably wouldn't have known what to look for to begin with.

Comment: I assure you Rust's documentation is the best thing around to answer many questions. Just need to get used to it